# How can I use FIFO to wait someone write in and read?

Tags: c, linux, fifo

As title, I use C to do this job between two programs in Linux system.
But, I encounter some problem.
Assuming that I have a server write data to FIFO in ten rounds, and
the client will read each round data and write another FIFO to feed 
back to server.
The client will block in each round until that the server writer data in.
However, my client program can't do this.

I use `fopen` to open the FIFO and `fgets` to read data.
It seems not to block to wait data write in.

client code:

```
FILE *fp_R,*fp_W;
char temp[100];
fp_R = fopen(FIFO_R,"rb");
fp_W = fopen(FIFO_W,"wb");
for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++ ) {
   fgets(temp, 100, fp_R);
   Handle Data;
   fprintf(fp_W,DATA);
}
```

I want to `fgets` to wait for server writing data in, so that I can handle each round

Thanks for anyone help

Comment: Please post some code, I don't understand your problem

Comment: Hi, I add some code hope this can help you undestand

Comment: Look at the man page for fopen()... it returns a FILE * , not an int.  You may want to use open() instead...  You have a similar problem with fgets() and fprintf()... they expects a FILE *.

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/open.html

Comment: What are FIFO_R and FIFO_W?  Were they created with mkfifo (Linux) or  CreateNamedPipe (Windows)?  If you're just using files, it does not work like a FIFO

Comment: FIFO_R and FIFO_W are created by server by mkfifo

Comment: It is operating system specific. Some mention at least Linux, or POSIX, or some other OS. Standard C99 does not know about FIFOs. So **edit your question** to improve it

Comment: I have modified the code

Answer (score 1):

as TonyB said, the `fopen()` function will return a file pointer `FILE*`

```
FILE *fp_R, *fp_W;
char temp[100];
fp_R = fopen(FIFO_R,"rb");
fp_W = fopen(FIFO_W,"wb");
for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++ ) {
   char* ret = fgets(temp, 100, fp_R);
   while(ret == null)
   {
    Sleep(1);
   }
   Handle Data;
   fprintf(fp_W,DATA);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`read(2)` on a fifo will block until there's data available, or the writing side `close(2)`es its open FD.  (In which case you will get EOF).

---

Run your program under `strace`, to see the system calls it makes.

e.g.

#### Reading side

```
peter@tesla:/tmp$ mkfifo mypipe
peter@tesla:/tmp$ strace cat mypipe
execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "mypipe"], [/* 69 vars */]) = 0
...
open("mypipe", O_RDONLY   # blocks until a writer opens the fifo
...    # after starting the writing side:
                = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
mmap(NULL, 139264, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f70d245c000    # cat allocates a buffer.  This might be from C stdio, or more likely custom buffering in GNU cat
read(3, "lkjsalkfj\n", 131072)          = 10
write(1, "lkjsalkfj\n", 10lkjsalkfj
)             = 10
read(3,   # blocked on a read system call
```

---

#### Writing side:

note that my shell opened the pipe before running `cat`.
I could have done
`strace tee /tmp/mypipe > /dev/null`

```
$ strace cat > /tmp/mypipe
... 
read(0, lkjsalkfj
"lkjsalkfj\n", 131072)          = 10
write(1, "lkjsalkfj\n", 10)             = 10
```

So the suggestions to add a `sleep(3)` are nonsense.  Your code looks like it should work.  You're probably doing something else wrong, and you should use `strace` to find it, since that's often easier than adding error-checking to your system calls in toy programs.  **Most of the code in real systems programming is checking error conditions from system calls, and handling them.**

I wouldn't be surprised if your reads aren't blocking because they're returning right away with an error.

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 line and try as below:

```
int fp_R,fp_W;
char temp[100];
fp_R = fopen(FIFO_R,"rb");
fp_W = fopen(FIFO_W,"wb");
for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++ ) {
   sleep(1); or usleep(10);//try it fgets will wait for some time bcz of this
   fgets(temp, 100, fp_R);
   Handle Data;
   fprintf(fp_W,DATA);
}
```

Comment: `read(2)` on a fifo will block until there's data available, or the writing side `close(2)es` its open FD.  (in which case you will get EOF).